# How to return boolean value from a function in Swift

Tags: xcode, function, swift, boolean

I've looked around but was suprised that I couldn't really find anything that explained this. If I have:

```
func checkEmail ()

{
   var test = true

   return test
}

...elsewhere in the code....

var emailStatus = checkEmail ()
```

How can I make this function return the boolean value of true?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
func checkEmail() -> Bool {
   var test = true
   return test
}
```

Elsewhere in the code....

```
var emailStatus = checkEmail()
```